# Can't insert MySQL query in Rails 5 (Lynda Course)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm taking a course on Lynda.com (Ruby on Rails 5 Essential Training) and I'm having an issue with adding a record on a table. Here's some details: The objective is to create a joint table, Many-to-Many association, so we're first trying to create a record on with of the tables we want to use on the new table. And everytime I write this line:

```
section = Sections.create(:name => "Section One", :position => 1)
```

It gives me this

```
    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
 => #<Section id: nil, page_id: nil, name: "Section One", position: 1, visible: false, content_type: nil, content: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

I checked my code and everything seems fine. By the way inserting records on other tables works. It's just this table.

one important point, This table is a previously created table. It's the new one we're trying to create.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code from migrate:

```
class CreateSections < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]

  def up
    create_table :sections do |t|

      t.integer   "page_id"
      t.string    "name"
      t.integer   "position"
      t.boolean   "visible", :default => false
      t.string    "content_type"
      t.text      "content"
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index("sections", "page_id")
  end

  def down
    drop_table :sections
  end


end
```

Here is the Section model:

```
class Section < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :page
has_many :section_edits


end
```

Comment: Could you share the Section model? probably some association, constraints or minor detail there is not properly configured/working.

Comment: I added the Section model to the question.

Comment: check my answer, I hope it's clear enough :) posting the model code helped us to catch the error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by: `belongs_to :page` as the `page_id` is nil and by default Rails `belongs_to` helper is adding a presence validation to make sure that the association is valid.

To disable this behaviour (presence validation) you can use:

```
belongs_to :page, optional: true
```

as mentioned here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to

**or** you can add `page_id` to your `Section.create` call as mentioned by others:

```
page_id = 1 # or Page.first.id or any page id you need
section = Section.create(name: "Section One", position: 1, page_id: page_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from `belongs_to :page`
If you try with `create!`, you should see this error message:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Page must exist

Just add `page_id` in your section creation:

```ruby
page_id = 1 # or Page.first.id or any page id you need
section = Section.create(name: "Section One", position: 1, page_id: page_id)
```