# Mysql query rollbacks after beginning

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm taking a course on Lynda.com (Ruby on Rails 5 Essential Training). It is almost the same question as [Can't insert MySQL query in Rails 5 (Lynda Course)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52078024/cant-insert-mysql-query-in-rails-5-lynda-course]).

I have an issue with Many-to-Many association-Rich. The error comes when I write this line:

```
section = Section.create(:name => 'Section One', :position => 1)
```

Error is:

```
(0.3ms)  BEGIN
(0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<Section id: nil, page_id: nil, name: "Section One", position: 1, visible: false, content_type: nil, content: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

I am following the course.

Migrate.rb looks like this:

```
class CreateSectionEdits < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    create_table :section_edits do |t|
      t.integer "admin_user_id"
      t.integer "section_id"
      t.string "summary"
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index("section_edits", ["admin_user_id", "section_id"])
  end

  def down
    drop_table :section_edits
  end
end
```

Sectionedit.rb looks like this:

```
class SectionEdit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :admin_users, optional: true  
  belongs_to :section
end
```

admin_user.rb looks like this:

```
class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord
  #self.table_name = "admin_users"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :pages
  has_many :section_edits
end
```

section.rb looks like this:

```
class Section < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :page, { :optional => false}
  has_many :section_edits
end
```

My error is not resolved. Please see. Looking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Section model, you wrote `belongs_to :page, { :optional => false}`, `page` is not optional so you have to assign a `page` to `section`

You can do something like this:

```
page = Page.create(:field => 'something') # or page = Page.find(page_id), it depends on your app’s business logic
section = Section.create(:name => 'Section One', :position => 1, :page => page)
```

Comment: ok, so i removed the optional part from the section.rb and then used this code to obtain this error :- 

` section = Section.create(:name => 'Section One', :position => 1, :page => "First Page")
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):8
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Page(#70214269276300) expected, got "First Page" which is an instance of String(#70214272581140))
`

Comment: @AmanRelan is your belongs_to :page association optional? if it is, change   `belongs_to :page, { :optional => false}` to `belongs_to :page, { :optional => true}` and `section = Section.create(:name => 'Section One', :position => 1)` would work fine. If it is not optional, you should always assign a page object (not string, in your case it should not be “First Page”) to section when you try to create a section record. It would be helpful if you can post what columns are there in pages and sections tables.

Comment: Thanks buddy, the `belongs_to :page, { :optional => true}` helped.. it worked.